# Find isomorphism between $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ and $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Find isomorphism between $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ and $\mathbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$.

---

It is easy to construct an injection $f$ satisfying $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. However, I am stuck how to construct such a mapping that is bijective.

Thank you for help!

Comment: What injection did you come up with? If it is actually additive then it should take 0 to 0...

Comment: @ThomasGrubb sorry, I did not make it clear. I mean the problem lies in satisfying one-one, not taking 0 to 0.

Comment: An injection on finite sets of the same cardinality is a bijection so you should be good then!

Comment: If $\phi$ is a (non-zero) ring morphism $K \to F$ and $K$ is a field, then $\phi$ is a field isomorphism $K \to \phi(K)$.

Comment: @user1952009 I understand the principle you mention. Could you please explain how to construct the $\phi$?

Comment: You want a field isomorphism, I believe.

Comment: @Lubin yes, it should be a field isomorphism

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $y$ is a solution to 
$$y^3+y^2+1=0$$ then $y+1$ is a solution to 
$$x^3+x+1=0.$$

Comment: Funny, I would have said that if $y$, then $1/y$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^2=x (\mod 2) $

So $F_2[x]/(x^3+x+1) \simeq F[x]/(2,x^3+x+1) \simeq  F[x]/(2,x^3+x^2+1) \simeq F_2[x]/ (x^3+x^2+1) $

Comment: This answer is wrong: $x$ is an indeterminate, not an element of $\mathbb F_2$ or $\mathbb Z$. (Only the answerer knows what is $F$ in his answer.)